# html form - make inputs appear on the same line

Tags: html, forms, css, input

I am struggling to make two html form inputs (first and last name) appear on the same line side by side. I have tried using float, but that seems to make the rest of the inputs go everywhere. Any advise would be greatly appreciated - here is my code:

**HTML:**

```html
<form action="includes/contact.php" method="post">

    <label for="First_Name">First Name:</label>
    <input name="first_name" id="First_Name" type="text" />
    <label for="Name">Last Name:</label>
    <input name="last_name" id="Last_Name" type="text" /> 

    <label for="Email">Email:</label>
    <input name="email" id="Email" type="email" />

    <label for="Telephone">Telephone:</label>
    <input name="telephone" id="Telephone" type="tel" />

    <label for="Wedding">Wedding Date:</label>
    <input name="wedding" id="Wedding" type="date" />

    <label for="Requirements">Specific Requirements:</label>
    <textarea name="requirements" id="Requirements" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"> </textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#contactpage form {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

#contactpage form label {
  margin-top:12px;
  font-size: 1.15em;
  color: #333333;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

#contactpage form input {
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
}

#contactpage form input[type='text'] {
  width: 22%;
  display: inline!important;
  background: #F9F9F9;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.4;
  padding: 6px;
}

#contactpage form input[type='email'],
#contactpage form input[type='tel'],
#contactpage form input[type='date'],
#contactpage form textarea {
  width: 94%;
  display: block;
  background: #F9F9F9;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.4;
  padding: 6px;
}

#contactpage form input[type='submit'] {    
  float:right;
  clear:both;
  display: block;
  background: #F9F9F9;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1.2;
  padding: 20px 20px 40px;
}

#contactpage form input[type='submit']:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #f1bdb5;
}
```

Here is the [JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/oCayInO/1/edit).

Comment: Use `display:inline-block` insted of `float`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can wrap the following in a DIV:

```
<div class="your-class">

  <label for="First_Name">First Name:</label>
  <input name="first_name" id="First_Name" type="text" />
  <label for="Name">Last Name:</label>
  <input name="last_name" id="Last_Name" type="text" /> 

</div>
```

Give each input `float:left` in your CSS:

```
.your-class input{
  float:left;
}
```

example only

You might have to adjust margins.

Remember to apply `clear:left` or both to whatever comes after `".your-class"`

Comment: At the time of the answer (2013 almost 2 years ago) display table wasn't fully supported, now it is: http://caniuse.com/#search=display%3Atable

Answer (score 53):

Wrap your multiple form elements in a `div` with a class that uses

```
display: table
```

Inside that `div`, wrap each `label` and `input` in `divs` with a class that uses

```
display: table-cell
```

Stay away from `floats`!

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

Comment: Everyone ignored this answer, but it's the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: Just wanted to reiterate the points that others have stated... this worked. Nothing else did. Also, check the reference. There are good reasons to avoid the accepted answer.

Answer (score 23):

A more modern solution:

Using `display: flex` and `flex-direction: row`

```css
form {
  display: flex; /* 2. display flex to the rescue */
  flex-direction: row;
}

label, input {
  display: block; /* 1. oh noes, my inputs are styled as block... */
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" />
  <label for="address">Address</label>
  <input type="text" id="address" />
  <button type="submit">
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

use table

```
<table align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"> 
<tr>
<td><label for="First_Name">First Name:</label></td>
<td><input name="first_name" id="First_Name" type="text" /></td>
<td><label for="last_name">Last Name:</label></td> <td> 
<input name="last_name" id="Last_Name" type="text" /></td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td colspan="2"><label for="Email">Email:</label></td> 
<td colspan="2"><input name="email" id="Email" type="email" /></td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td colspan="4"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td> 
</tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! The table worked perfectly for my simple input selection. And it's 2015 no less!

Comment: Might as well add that table is still valid in HTML5 even if you use role="presentation". Nevertheless there are other solutions like using css display table (which can be combined with media queries for making a different layout on lower res for example), using grids, flexbox, ...

Answer (score 1):

Try just putting a div around the first and last name inputs/labels like this:

```
<div class="name">
        <label for="First_Name">First Name:</label>
        <input name="first_name" id="First_Name" type="text" />

        <label for="Name">Last Name:</label>
        <input name="last_name" id="Last_Name" type="text" /> 
</div>
```

Look at the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/XAkXg/

Answer (score 1):

You can make a class for each label and inside it put:

```
display: inline-block;
```

And `width` the value that you need.

Answer (score 0):

This test shows three blocks of two blocks together on the same line.

```css
.group {
    display:block;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.group>div {
    display:inline-block;
    padding-bottom:4px;
}
.group>div>span,.group>div>div {
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
}

input[type=text] {
    height:1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
    <div>
        <span>First Name</span>
        <span><input type="text"/></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>Last Name</div>
        <div><input type="text"/></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>Address</div>
        <div><input type="text"/></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wondering how to do this with tailwind, here is an approach:

```
<div className="block">
    <div className="inline-block">
    </div>
    <div className="inline-block">
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not the greatest FED so feedback is appreciated! Thanks!!