# Make name appear on the same line nicely

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place the firstname and the lastname on the same line.
I looked over this question:

[html form - make inputs appear on the same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470682/html-form-make-inputs-appear-on-the-same-line)

But because of my old css (used in app), the fields aren't correctly displayed. I need a little space between the two fields.
I made a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/up5bL2xn/

EDIT: My html code:

```
 <div class="parent-split-row">
  <div class="child-split-row">
    <label class="form-label">
      First Name
    </label>
    <input type="text"
      id="js-input-first-name"
      name="first_name"
      class="form-input"
      value="{{ form.first_name.vars.value|default }}"
      placeholder="First Name"
      onkeyup="VALIDATIONS.onKeyUp('js-coach-license-registration-form','js-input-first-name')"
      onmouseup="VALIDATIONS.onMouseUp('js-coach-license-registration-form','js-input-first-name')"
      autofocus>
    <div id="js-input-first-name__error"
      class="form-validation">
      Please fill in your First Name
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child-split-row">
    <label class="form-label">
      Last Name
    </label>
    <input type="text"
      id="js-input-last-name"
      name="last_name"
      class="form-input"
      value="{{ form.last_name.vars.value|default }}"
      placeholder="Last Name"
      onkeyup="VALIDATIONS.onKeyUp('js-coach-license-registration-form','js-input-last-name')"
      onmouseup="VALIDATIONS.onMouseUp('js-coach-license-registration-form','js-input-last-name')"
      autofocus>
    <div id="js-input-last-name__error"
      class="form-validation">
      Please fill in your Last Name
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your CSS file:

```
.child-split-row:not(:last-child) {
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

That's one way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go! just added a padding-right on the first name and divided the label and input in two different div's :)

```css
.name{
  float: left;
  padding-right: 4%;
}
```

```html
<div class="name">
        <label for="First_Name">First Name:</label>
        <input name="first_name" id="First_Name" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="lastname">
        <label for="Name">Last Name:</label>
        <input name="last_name" id="Last_Name" type="text" /> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I chose another answer because it was shorten and I didn't want to divide again the label.

Answer (score 1):

> use "&nbsp" after your first div class="child-split-row" or else add padding right to your css for child-split-row class

```
.child-split-row {
padding-right:10px;
}
```

```css
.parent-split-row {
    display: table;
}

.child-split-row {
    display: table-cell;
}

.form-label {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    color: #1f1f1f;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 2px;
}

.form-input {
    font-family: Aileron;
    font-weight: 500;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    color: #1f1f1f;
    background-color: #d6d5d6;
    border: 1px solid #d6d5d6;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 34px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-split-row">
      <div class="child-split-row">
        <label class="form-label">
          First Name
        </label>
        <input type="text"
          id="js-input-first-name"
          name="first_name"
          class="form-input"
          placeholder="First Name">
      
      </div>&nbsp&nbsp
      <div class="child-split-row">
        <label class="form-label">
          Last Name
        </label>
        <input type="text"
          id="js-input-last-name"
          name="last_name"
          class="form-input"
          placeholder="Last Name">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this. ;)

```
.parent-split-row { display: flex; }
```