# django forms and filter - how to render the DateFromToRangeFilter so the from and to input fields are in a row?

Tags: django-forms, django-filter, django-crispy-forms

I'm trying to use django-filter DateFromToRangeFilter.  The problem is the widget always renders as a stack.  What I'd like is the two input fields to be side by side.  Nothing I try is changing this.  Here's what results: [it's the filter by date range area]
[image: What I'm currently seeing]

The filters.py definition of this field is:

```
change_date = DateFromToRangeFilter(field_name='change_date',
                                        label='Filter by Date Range:',
                                        widget=RangeWidget(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
```

change_date is a django-tables2 `DateColumn`.  Nothing special there.

The form is defined using crispy: [here's the layout]

```
self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(
                Div(
                    InlineCheckboxes('category'),
                    css_class="border bg-light",
                ),
                Div(
                    Field('change_date', css_class='form-control form-control-sm'),
                    css_class="border d-flex flex-row ",
                ),
                Div(
                    Submit('submit', 'Filter', css_class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"),
                    HTML(my_url),
                    css_class="col-md",
                ),
                css_class="d-flex flex-row g-2",
            ),
        )
```

If I inspect the html code, it looks like:
[image]

No matter how I define the layout, the two fields remain stacked. The `div id=div_id_change_date` seems to be where things need to change. How do you get these two input fields to lay-out in-line?  Do I have to create a custom widget?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the path to the answer here: [another stackoverflow question: html form - make inputs appear on the same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470682/html-form-make-inputs-appear-on-the-same-line)

A solution that works, but probably should be refined, is add some css a la:

```
.date-block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.date-block > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.date-block > input, label {
  display: block;
}
```

and then update the form:

```
Div(
     FloatingField('intake'),
     css_class="col-2 small date-block"
),
```

Probably a better way to do this would be to come up with my own crispy template to eliminate the `DIV` around the two `INPUT` and `LABEL` tags that the filter/form generates.